# upgrading setting after strongly naming an application

Tags: vb.net

I have .net application which is not strongly named.

On initial load the program checks to see if its version number has changed since its last use, and if it has executes the following two lines of code programmatically:

```
My.Settings.Upgrade()
My.Settings.Save()
```

This has worked well thru many version upgrades, with the user's old settings being automatically brought forward for use in the newer version.

However, I have now changed the options to have the program strongly named.

In doing so, the two lines above no longer upgrade the settings between the old version (not strongly named) and the new version (strongly named).

I've thought of writing some code to hunt thru the user's settings files and find the old settings and port them over programmatically, but am wondering if there is a more elegant way to approach this?

Comment: I had a similar problem where I was using config files for storing certain settings, and the location of the settings definitions changed, and I wound up loading the old files as XML and rewriting class definitions to point to the updated assembly.  I'm not sure if this is exactly the issue you have, but even if it's not your immediate problem, I'd bet you'll run into it.  I didn't find any other solution.